# Windows 2012 r2 shutdown randomly

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, windows-server-2008-r2, eclipse

I've been suffering a while from a problem on IBM server having windows 2012 R2 with RDS and Hyper V

developers are using RDS to connect on this machine or on the Hyper V virtual servers the Visual studio 2013 as well as eclipse and android development tools.

We are suffering from time to time a situation where the virtual server or the server itself shutdown randomly, without logging any event.

Any hint where to search?

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like hardware level failure

Comment: We need more information to be able to help you. What have you tried? Are there any crash dumps? What have you ruled out? Are there any signs that it will shutdown, or does it surprise you?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer as i just noticed tour reply. In fact we have tried changing the server, changing the stations, changing the antinvirus. it happens suddenly by giving a message : Server is shutting down"

Answer (score 0):

Random shutdowns happens on Windows Server 2012 R2 if trial has expired and not activated.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: Hey @DavidPostill, thanks for mentioning! Actually my reply can be considered as the answer, because lack of license is likely the **reason**, why this is happening. It's a common thing in environment, described by author. I just searched for resolution for the same issue myself, and wanted to share what helped us.

Comment: Yes, but the OP did not mention anything about a trial license ...

Comment: @DavidPostil, thought it would be strange to use non-trial license on dev VMs that were mentioned by author, as those usually have quite small life-cycle.

Comment: Fair enough ...